# Need Help Resolving SQLDateTime overflow error

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone assist with this error?
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Here's my code:

```
 <DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)> _
    Public Shared Sub UpdateIncident( _
                                    ByVal DateClosed As DateTime, _
                                    ByVal Description As String, _
                                    ByVal original_IncidentID As Integer, _
                                    ByVal original_ProductCode As String, _
                                    ByVal original_DateOpened As DateTime, _
                                    ByVal original_DateClosed As DateTime, _
                                    ByVal original_Title As String, _
                                    ByVal original_Description As String, _
                                    ByVal IncidentID As Integer, _
                                    ByVal ProductCode As String, _
                                    ByVal DateOpened As DateTime, _
                                    ByVal Title As String)
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString)
        Dim up As String = "UPDATE Incidents " _
           & "SET DateClosed = @DateClosed, " _
           & "Description = @Description" _
           & "WHERE IncidentID = @original_IncidentID " _
           & "AND ProductCode = @original_ProductCode " _
           & "AND DateOpened = @original_DateOpened " _
           & "AND (DateClosed = @original_DateClosed " _
           & "OR DateClosed IS NULL " _
           & "AND @original_DateClosed IS NULL) " _
           & "AND Title = @original_Title " _
           & "AND Description = @original_Description"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(up, con)
        If DateClosed = #12:00:00 AM# Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", DBNull.Value)
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", DateClosed)
            cmd.Parameters("DateClosed").DbType = DbType.DateTime
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", Description)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_IncidentID", original_IncidentID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_ProductCode", original_ProductCode)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateOpened", original_DateOpened)
        cmd.Parameters("original_DateOpened").DbType = DbType.DateTime
        If original_DateClosed = #12:00:00 AM# Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateClosed", original_DateClosed)
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_DateClosed", original_DateClosed)
            cmd.Parameters("original_DateClosed").DbType = DbType.DateTime
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_Title", original_Title)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("original_Description", original_Description)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you have a DateTime that you have not set. The .NET DateTime.MinValue is '01/01/0001 00:00' and the SqlDateTime minimum value is the 1753 value. Just make sure that none of your DateTime's remain unset before sending the data to the database.

UPDATE:

In the method you have defined, add some logic to find and fix DateTime.MinValue's that are passed to you. Please accept my C#,

```
if (theDateTime < SqlDateTime.MinValue)
{
    theDateTime = SqlDateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ed... Thanks but the problem is that some of the records in the database that I'm working on have to remain empty until the user logs in and puts an DateClosed on them...  I'm not sure how to amend my code to account for that... Any thoughts... I'm a newbie!  Don't know how to fix... this is my first ASP class

Comment: Whoops!  Hit enter too soon...  Isn't that what I've done here...  See code:   If DateClosed = #12:00:00 AM# Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", DBNull.Value)
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateClosed", DateClosed)
            cmd.Parameters("DateClosed").DbType = DbType.DateTime2
        End If

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server datetime datatype has range: January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

.NET DateTime datatype has range: 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D

You can use SQL Server 2008's new datatype: [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

Comment: Tried that... still get the error... using Visual Studio 2010... Any other ideas?

Comment: Tried what? changing the table column(s) to datetime2?